# a strange error in racket "no expression after a sequence of internal definitions"

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following code:

```
(define (play-loop strat0 strat1 strat2 game-limit)
 (define (play-loop-iter strat0 strat1 strat2 count history0 history1 history2 limit)
  (cond ((= count limit) (print-out-results history0 history1 history2 limit))
      (else (let ((result0 (strat0 history0 history1 history2))
                  (result1 (strat1 history0 history1 history2)
                  (result2 (strat2 history0 history1 history2)))
              (play-loop-iter strat0 strat1 strat2 (+ 1 count)
                              (extend-history result0 history0)
                              (extend-history result1 history1)
                              (extend-history result2 history2)
                              limit)))))
 (play-loop-iter strat0 strat1 strat2 0 '() '() '() game-limit)))
```

When I run it in racket it gives me the following error:

begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in:...

I seems everything is OK but there is an error and looked me very interesting.

What is the problem?

Thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you that your `play-loop` function only contains the definition of the `play-loop-iter` function and no other expression in its body.

It looks like you want the call to `play-loop-iter` to be part of `play-loop`'s body, but it's not - it's part of `play-loop-iter`'s body. Check the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely missing a paren after `(result1 (strat1 history0 history1 history2)`

Comment: It's true that he's missing a parenthesis there, but that's not what's causing that particular error message. The error message for that would be "bad syntax (missing binding pairs or body)". He'd probably get that error message after fixing the other error.

Comment: yes it fixed the syntax error thank you very much but there was some other errors.